# iOS App Icon Stretched

Tags: iphone, ios, icon

I recently noticed that in iOS 7 my app icon stretches:

[image]

And here is how it is supposed to be:

[image]

This is only in iOS 7. What should I do? Should I contact Apple?

Comment: Is it happening with only this app or many other apps too?

Comment: @KaranRajBaruah Only this app(I programed the app)

Answer (score 3):

> If you want to target only iOS 7, you just need 76 x 76, >120 x 120 and 152 x 152 icon sizes.
>   If you want to target also iOS 6, you’ll need 57 x 57, 72 x >72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x
>   120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. Without >counting Spotlight and Settings icon if
>   you don’t want the OS to interpolate them!

If you change the resolution of the app icons the problem should be fixed.

Source: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons